# HTML Javascript Canvas - Multiple Canvases stacked cause delay

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, canvas

I'm making an app using Phonegap/Cordova, and I have seem to come along an unusual lag. I have multiple canvases around:

canvasTop - Seperate canvas for top navigation

canvasBot - Seperate canvas for bottom navigation

canvasSide - Seperate canvas for a menu slider

Now my program runs perfectly, until strangely enough, when I add a 4th canvas, `canvasTopNav` (a seperate sliding canvas for the top navigation), the app lags very badly; even though the canvas is declared/drawn offscreen. The canvas is only drawn once and moved around using `style.top`.

Does declaring multiple canvases like this supposed to cause so much lag?

This is pretty much all I do:

```
ctxTopNav.style.top = -cTopNav.height;
ctxTopNav.fillStyle = "#F4F4F4";
ctxTopNav.fillRect(0, 0, cTopNav.width, cTopNav.height);
```

I do not use `clearRect`, nor do I add or redraw anything on the canvas.

Once I remove this specific block of code, the app works great.

The code works fine, just getting bad lag

Comment: How large (resolution) are the canvases. You may have gone over the available GPU RAM and lag is due to switching the canvas in and out of GPU RAM. Ensure that the canvas resolution is not higher than display size. Apart from that you have not provided enough information to solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking that, but don't know how to quite analyze performance. On separate devices the lag is reduced significantly.

RAM reads 27MB Allocated/12MB Free
While non laggy device reads 75MB Allocated/12MB Free

Comment: Each canvas is close to full resolution

Comment: It is not the device RAM that will just halt your app if you run out, it is the Graphics (GPU)  RAM that is important. A rough estimate for GPU RAM is 4bytes per pixel so a 1024 by 1024 canvas needs 4Mb. Each pixel of each displayable resource (images, canvas, and background page) should be accounted for. If the canvases are full res (whatever that is i  have no clue) I would say you are close to low end device capabilities. Can you reduce the resolution of any of the canvases. Halving two of them should regain the performance.

Comment: Very interesting.. lowering the resolution does in fact eliminate the lag.. So it doesn't matter where my canvases are positioned, even off display or stacked, the GPU Ram still counts?

Comment: Also, am I right to assume GPU ram is generally very little amount?

Comment: The GPU RAM will depend on the device. It is usually a ratio between screen resolution and GPU RAM. Low end (budget) devices will have a low ratio. The total amount is not important, the number of times you can create a copy the screen in GPU RAM is. Unfortunately there is no way to know by Javascript what is available. There is also some Chip specific issues to do with how pixels are stored but again low end usually dont have the goods.